# Sub Report embedded in footer of Crystal report not showing data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that has a subreport embedded in it's footer. The reports individually work fine, but when I run together, I don't get data in the subreport. I have verified that the data exists in my 2 datasets, and I get data for my primary report, but not the sub. What am I missing? (VS 2008 4.0 .NET Framework)

```
// check whether the dataset is manual; if so add the subreport queries
        if (AARpt.HasSubreports)
        {
            string srName;
            string sProc;
            using (AAData dc = new AAData(AAApp, true))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects.Count; i++)
                {
                    ReportObject CurrentObject = cRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[i];
                    if (CurrentObject.Kind == CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                    {
                        SubreportObject sr = (SubreportObject)CurrentObject;
                        rd = sr.OpenSubreport(sr.SubreportName );
                        srName = sr.SubreportName;

                        if (AARpt.SubReps.TryGetValue(srName, out sProc))
                        {
                            dsSubRept = dc.LoadSet(sProc);

                            if (dsSubRept != null)
                            {
                                DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables["MyTable"];
                                rd.SetDataSource(dt1);
                                rd.VerifyDatabase();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("We're sorry, but an error was encountered attempting to create this report","Utility", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
        }

    public DataSet LoadSet(SqlCommand _cmd)
    {
        // returns table "MyTable"
        SqlDataAdapter DA;
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();

        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _cmd.Connection = _Conn;

        DA = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        DA.Fill(DS, "MyTable");

        return DS;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong dataset for the subreport....otherwise it was perfect. Updated code below.

```
// check whether the dataset is manual; if so add the subreport queries
        if (AARpt.HasSubreports)
        {
            string srName;
            string sProc;
            using (AAData dc = new AAData(AAApp, true))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects.Count; i++)
                {
                    ReportObject CurrentObject = cRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[i];
                    if (CurrentObject.Kind == CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                    {
                        SubreportObject sr = (SubreportObject)CurrentObject;
                        rd = sr.OpenSubreport(sr.SubreportName );
                        srName = sr.SubreportName;

                        if (AARpt.SubReps.TryGetValue(srName, out sProc))
                        {
                            dsSubRept = dc.LoadSet(sProc);

                            if (dsSubRept != null)
                            {
                                // Following line added (not sure if needed, but was suggested in several spots)
                                rd.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
                                // The datasource in the following line changed - this was my real issue
                                DataTable dt1 = dsSubRept.Tables["MyTable"];
                                rd.SetDataSource(dt1);
                                rd.VerifyDatabase();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("We're sorry, but an error was encountered attempting to create this report","Utility", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    // The following is part of a class for loading data, but it is straightforward otherwise
    // I just included so you know that it returns a DataSet with a table named "MyTable"
    public DataSet LoadSet(SqlCommand _cmd)
    {
        // returns table "MyTable"
        SqlDataAdapter DA;
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();

        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _cmd.Connection = _Conn;

        DA = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        DA.Fill(DS, "MyTable");

        return DS;

    }
```